# Twitter v2 api proportional rate limit

Tags: twitter-api-v2

We have basic access to the twitter v2 api and are routinely rate limited, but the next step up (pro) is well beyond our needs, and 50x the cost.

To anyone within twitter, is it possible to negotiate a custom rate plan based on our actual needs, with a proportional price, or are there any plans to implement such?